# Question on solution of differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of the differential equation

$$(1 + y^2) + [x − e^{\arctan(y)}]\frac {dy}{dx} = 0 $$

---

A hint with the question says that this will reduce to a linear differential equation. I am unable to do the same.

Comment: Hint: Think of the derivative of the $\arctan$.

Comment: it is $$y \left( x \right) =\tan \left( \ln  \left( x-\sqrt {{x}^{2}-2\,{\it 
\_C1}} \right)  \right) 
$$ or $$y \left( x \right) =\tan \left( \ln  \left( x+\sqrt {{x}^{2}-2\,{\it 
\_C1}} \right)  \right) 
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Have you tried making the substitution $u=\arctan y$ and $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac1{1+y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}$?